# What is air entrainment in the context of cement mortars and how is it achieved?

Tags: materials, terminology, masonry

What is **air entrainment** in the context of cement mortars and how is it achieved?

I'm not an engineer but I would like to get a rudimentary understanding of the mechanism whereby tiny bubbles of air could remain entrapped in mortar when an air-entrapping liquid gets mixed into the sand-and-cement mixture.

Supposedly this entrapped air mitigates the effects of freeze-thaw by creating tiny air-filled cavities to allow for expansion and contraction. But I don't understand how grains of sand embedded in a crystalline lattice can move around, even at a microscopic level. Or does the air-entrapping chemical somehow add some ductility to those crystalline structures, or allow them to "crumble" and then reform without  the bubbles of air bursting? Or do the air bubbles surround the grains of sand, so there's some "cushion" between them and the crystalline lattice? Or does the crystalline lattice in which the grains of sand are embedded remain fixed, and the air bubbles give the *water* some place to go, so it doesn't destroy the lattice?

Comment: I was hoping to get an engineering explanation of how the bubbles actually get created and then confined in the mix. You know, a "materials science" answer.  If I asked "how do lightbulbs work" would you refer me to an Amazon page for an on/off switch?